# glassfish server admin console stalls saying: The admin console application is loaded

Tags: glassfish, ejb, jersey, ear

I am having some trouble getting into my glassfish server admin console (although I think it may actually be a symptom of a larger problem)

What I am seeing is that when I go to: http://localhost:4848/ I get a page that says: Welcome to glassfish server open source edition 3.1 (build 43) and then a status section below that. The status makes it to "The admin console application is loaded" but seems to stall there. If I refresh the page, it is just a blank page. I have to reboot the glassfish server from eclipse in order to get back to that "welcome to glassfish" page.

I looked in my server logs and found a ton of "SEVERE" problems, all of which seem to relate to this one:

```
[#|2011-10-06T18:03:10.869-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=100;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Error reading configuration file
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
|#]
```

Has anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on here? I'm very new to glassfish and rather confused! Thanks in advance.

Avtar

Answer (score 0):

I think I had similar problem when running on Open JDK, check which JDK are you using, if its' openjdk then dowload and set as your default sun-jdk

Comment: I was using open jdk and that wasn't working earlier in the process. I actually had to switch it in eclipse to get this far. I switched it by going to window/preferences/server/runtime environment, editing my glassfish server and setting it to the sun-jdk. Is there anywhere else I need to set it?